# Prove probability of event i.o. equal to 0 with given conditions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Suppose events $\left\{A_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are from a common probability space. And we have
>   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(A_n)=0,\qquad\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_nA_{n+1}^c)< \infty$$
>   Prove: $P(A_n \text{ i.o.})=0$.

I think it can be proved using Borel-Cantelli lemma. But not sure how to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)< \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: show that the event

$$\left(\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k\right) \triangle \left(\bigcup_{k \ge n} (A_k \cap A_{k+1}^c)\right)$$
has zero probability. Here, the symmetric difference is defined by $B \triangle C := (B\cup C) - (B\cap C)$.

This will allow you to transfer the result of Borel-Cantelli on $\{A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c\}_{n=1}^\infty$ to $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

---

Edit:

The above symmetric difference is contained in $\bigcup_{k \ge n} \bigcap_{j \ge k} A_j$. [Check this.]

Then,
\begin{align}
P\left\{\left(\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k\right) \triangle \left(\bigcup_{k \ge n} (A_k \cap A_{k+1}^c)\right)\right\}
&\le
P\left(\bigcup_{k \ge n} \bigcap_{j \ge k} A_j\right)\\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty} P\bigcap_{j \ge k} A_j\\
&\le \lim_{k \to \infty} P(A_k)\\
&\to 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you see the symmetric difference has probability zero? I mean it's not something straightforward.

Comment: @LeiHao See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the details. What I mean is how do you know this is the way to go at the beginning. For example, my instinct tells me try to prove $\sum P（A_n）< \infty$, which doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: @LeiHao I guess the other condition $\sum_n P(A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c) < \infty$ looks like Borel-Cantelli, so I apply it to that first and try to go backward to fill in the gaps. But I agree it is not too obvious.